# Conversion from string literal to char *

Tags: c++, c, c++11

I am trying to make a c function work in some publicly available linear algebra code.

the publicly available prototype is…

```
int ilaenv_(int *, char *, char *, int *, int *,int *, int *);
```

The publicly available code has the function call…

```
nb = ilaenv_(&c__1, "DGEQRF", " ", m, n, &c_n1, &c_n1);
```

where m, n, c_1, and c_n1 are integers,

The error message is.

```
C++ 11 does not allow conversation from string literal to char *.
```

I did not create the code, but downloaded it from the LAPACK site. I hesitate to make too many changes to publicly available code that supposedly works, for fear of introducing errors.  However, this error is showing up on a number of functions in the program that I am working on.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: You can just cast constness but I don't know if that can be good.

Comment: Does it really say `conversation`? Please use the actual error strings. And fix the title.

Comment: Not a strict duplicate, but this should have some helpful information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704407/what-is-the-difference-between-char-s-and-char-s-in-c/1704433#1704433

Comment: Yes please post the exact error message, copy and paste, it's not possible that it says `conversation`.

Comment: I guess you can't talk about string literals and char* in c++11.  Freaken passive-aggressive language...

Comment: is parameter 3 space?

Comment: Oops.  one of those "spell checkers" got me again.  "conversation" should be conversion.   So the exact message is .... "C++ 11 does not allow conversion from string literal to char *

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for being so late, I just bumped into this problem. You can try this,

```
string dgeqrf = "DGEQRF";
```

One problem with using "const char *" is code like this,

```
string formatString;
switch (format)
{
    case FORMAT_RGB:  formatString = "RGB"; break;
    case FORMAT_RGBA: formatString = "RGBA"; break;
    case FORMAT_TP10: formatString = "TP10"; break;
    default:          formatString = "Unsupported"; break;
}
```

If you declare formatString as a "const char *", this won't work.

Comment: re. "if you declare `formatString` as a `const char *` this won't work" – the code shown here will work just fine with `const char *`, but the potential problem is that the function takes `char *` not `const char *` so we don't know if it is going to modify the contents of the string, and modifying the string literals is not permitted. Hence the need to have a modifiable array, either by conversion from `string` or as a `char` array instead of pointer (as per my answer). _Unless_ you need to assign the contents dynamically (like in this answer), the array is simpler.

Answer (score 8):

Your function takes "char *", not "const char *". String literals can be assigned only to "const char *".

Answer (score 6):

To be safe, you could create `char` arrays initialised to the same values, for example:

```
char dgeqrf[] = "DGEQRF";
char space[] = " ";
```

Or you could check the source code of the function; if it doesn't actually modify the contents of those arrays you could change the arguments to `const char *`.

Comment: Thank you.  This looks like the direction to go.

Comment: Creating the character string successfully removed the error.